# Elasticsearch - search bulk update providing index data as param in rest api call

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using neo4j and I want to use elasticsearch in my java project. since because of lucene dependency issues , i can't use elasticsearch in java api and neo4j together .

I need to do bulk update in elasticsearch . I need to know whether there is an rest api for bulk update in elasticsearch which accepts "data to be indexed" as params or body of rest api call .

I have seen example of (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) but it is using file having json objects.

Comment: that doc does show the REST bulk update api. It's taking requests from a file, but that's just because it's an example using curl

Comment: do I need to write it in url like : <XXXX:9200/index/type?d={jsondocument},{otherjsondocument}

Comment: No - the bulk data goes in the body of the request

Comment: body of request separated by "\n" as per documentation

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j

The river will sync/pull the data from Neo4J.

Comment: I'd recommend against the use of rivers, as they sometimes unreliable and are to be depreciated soon. An alternative is to use a message queue and the bulk API https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Official-guide-writing-ElasticSearch-rivers-3393294.S.268274223

Comment: I need to get each nodes along with its relationship in single document , which neo4j river plugin doesn't do.

Comment: Couldn't you clone/fork the github project and modify the code? You can write your own IndexingStrategy implementation (don't forget the DeleteStrategy).

See [link](https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/river/neo4j/SimpleIndexingStrategy.java) for the current implementaton.